# Displaying the result from DetailView at ListView

Tags: django, django-views

I have written a calculation on DetailView named **result_xyz** as follows:

```
class Model01_DV(DetailView):

    queryset = Model01.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = Model01_DV, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        x_ = # first dependency
        y_ = # second dependency
        z_ = # third dependency

        result_xyz = # sophisticated calculation that involves x, y and z variables

        context["result_xyz"] = result_xyz

        return context
```

Is there a way to display this resultant value on each row table that is generated by ListView?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing shouldn't be done in the view at all. Make it a model method, then you can reference it from both the list and detail views.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of how this can be done in a model method? This calculation does not only involve mathematical formula, but it also includes if statement and for loop.